# SERVICE UNAVAILABLE error at REST API calling

Tags: api, rest, laravel-8

My API route in `routes/api.php` file is like below.

```
Route::post('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'register']);
```

My `register` function of `RegisterController` is like below

```
public function register(RegistrationValidate $request)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'username' => request('username'),
            'email' => request('email'),
            'full_name' => request('full_name'),
            'store_name' => request('store_name'),
            'store_logo' => $fileName,
            'password' => Hash::make(request('password')),            
        ]);

        $token = $user->createToken($this->clientToken())->accessToken;
        return response()->json([
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token,
        ], 201);
    }
```

I am getting `SERVICE UNAVAILABLE` error like below

[image: error]

I used `php artisan up` command and clear the cache. But the result is as like before.

Comment: I would expect a 404 if this route wasnt registered properly. Do you have some kind of load balancer or anything in front of your php backend? Usually, I would expect a 503, if the load balancer cant reach the backend. That said, I dont write php, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thanks @TheFool. No, I don't use any kind of load balancer or anything in front of PHP back end.

Comment: Can you try to hit some route that cleary doesnt exist? What status code do you get there? Something like http://127.0.0.1:8000/foobar.

Comment: Thanks @TheFool. I am getting this result.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCoqJ.png  . Thanks

Comment: Does `User::create` interact with a database or some other kind of server over the network?

Comment: Can you try adding some exception handling. I'm not very familiar with your environment, but maybe this handler throws an exception that is caught somewhere else (maybe even by the framework itself) where a 503 is retruned? Or just try removing all code from the handler and returing only a statuscode, just to verify the route is hit. If that works, the error happens somewhere in `User::create`  or `user->createToken`

Comment: As the error comes from server so, first you can restart the server. Then please check the error log of laravel. If the issue is not solved, then put the code in try catch block and see any error shows up.